# How to synchronize birthdates from contacts with google calendar on HTC Hero?

Tags: contacts, sync, calendar, htc-hero

I'm aware of the fact that the standard contacts/calendar app does not support birthdates synchronization (Android issue [1211](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1211)). But may be there is some third-party software which can make those synchronized for me?

Answer (score 5):

Is this still a problem? I see birthdays from contacts in Calendar.

I add birthdays to my contacts in Gmail, and I subscribed to the "Contacts' birthdays and events" in Google Calendar:

1. Under "Other calendars" Add > Browse
2. Select "Interesting Calendars"
3. Select "Contacts' birthdays and events"

This gives me a calendar in Google Calendar with my contact's birthdays.

When I got my android (a motorola xt720 running eclair), the birthday calendar showed in the Calendar app.

You'll probably have to open the Calendar app > Menu > My Calendars. And then Menu > Add calendars. You should see Contacts' birthdays and events.

Comment: Likely this is just a change in Google Calendar since 2010, but when you go to "Interesting Calendars" you have to select the "More" tab as it defaults to "holidays"

Answer (score 2):

[gCalBirthdays](http://code.google.com/p/gcalbirthdays/) is what you're looking for. It comes as a Google Calendar Sidebar Gadget and reads your contacts birthdays in one of your Google calendars which you can then sync to your android phone.